# How can I login to cPanel different ways

Tags: cpanel

## From how many ways can I log in to cPanel or In how many ways I can access to my cPanel ?

I want to ask that is there any another way to login to cPanel ? Please

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of logging into a cPanel/WHM server.  Many of these logins are for different types of access.  Below are the common logon screens assuming any_donmain.tld is a domain hosted on the server or the server IP address.

- WHM:  for performing administrative functions

  - https://any_donmain.tld2087 or http://any_donmain.tld/whm
- cPanel: for your web-hosting control panel.

  - https://any_donmain.tld:2083 or http://any_donmain.tld/cpanel
- Webmail:  For checking email accounts

  - https://any_donmain.tld:2096 or http://any_donmain.tld/webmail

Additionally there is a command line interface on your server called SSH.  You will need to contact your server provider for information on accessing ssh including the port it runs on.